# Angular web components & routing

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-elements

I am working with Angular Web Components like shown in example [here](https://medium.com/swlh/build-micro-frontends-using-angular-elements-the-beginners-guide-75ffeae61b58).

All web components are displayed fine in the parent app (e.g. `http://localhost:8080/dashboard`) but my current problem is that I have a button in my web component and I need go to the web component profile (e.g. `http://localhost:8080/dashboard/profile`).

I have tried several examples but none worked.

Could someone guide me please? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Show us your routing component code

Comment: @Tzimpo I don't know how do the routing in the custom web component and make it work in the parent app.

Comment: @beanic I have the same problem have u reached any solution or workaround?

Answer (score 0):

A little of your code would be useful to see what you currently have and what might be wrong with it.

In your dashboard.component.html file you would want to have a button or link element () which links to your router:

```
<a routerLink="/dashboard/profile">Login</a>
```

Your app-routing.module.ts should have something along the lines of:

```
// standard imports
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

// importing your component to route to 
import { DashboardProfileComponent } from './dashboardprofile/dashboardprofile.component';

// your route
const routes: Routes = [
  {path: 'dashboard/profile', component: DashboardProfileComponent},
];

// standard
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Don't forget to import your routing module in your app.module.ts.
`app.module.ts`

```
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
```

Answer (score 0):

@beanic I found a workaround by using Inputs and Outputs with the web-component Output you will emit your target path and wrap your  inside your web-component tags like :

```
    <navigation><router-outlet></router-outlet></navigation>
```

and also add

```
<ng-content></ng-content>
```

in web-component where you want your view to be loaded.

Comment: Can you please elaborate this solution?